# Composing computed properties with other computed properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to write a custom filtered search, sort and paginate properties since my product cannot rely any of the out of box solutions mainly because I need to display images, icons, buttons and urls in my table.  Think of it as a product listing page with images and buy links.

My question is how do I chain multiple computed properties?

## Example

For Filtered Search:

```
computed: {
    filteredProds:function() {
        return this.prodlist.filter(prod => {
            return prod.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
        })
    }
```

and for sorting the table I have this computed property along with a method to do the sort.

```
myprods.sort((a,b) => {
  let modifier = 1;
  if(this.currentSortDir === 'desc') modifier = -1;
  if(a[this.currentSort] < b[this.currentSort]) return -1 * modifier;
  if(a[this.currentSort] > b[this.currentSort]) return 1 * modifier;
  return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as referencing them

```
data: {
  numbers: [1,2,3]
},
computed: {
  oddNumbers () {
    return this.numbers.filter(n => n % 2)
  },
  firstOddNumber () {
    return this.oddNumbers[0]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I managed to get it working by going through a tutorial on Lynda.com.