# Vuejs - computed property based on other computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to get a computed property from another computed property, like so:

```
var instance = new Vue({
    el: "#instance",
    data: {
        aha: ""
    },
    computed: {
        len: function(){
            return this.aha.length;
        },
        plus : function(){
            return this.len.length + 2;
        }
    }
});
```

This doesn't work. I get `NaN` in my template when I try to display `plus`. Is there a way to make this work? The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185265/composing-computed-properties-with-other-computed-properties) doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the `length` field of type `number`.

`this.len` is number, so `this.len.length` is undefined. you just need to use `this.len`:

```
var instance = new Vue({
    el: "#instance",
    data: {
        aha: ""
    },
    computed: {
        len: function(){
            return this.aha.length;
        },
        plus : function(){
            return this.len+ 2;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Right. Stupid mistake. Thank you.

Comment: why this does not work with arrow function ?

Answer (score 0):

`data` property in component must be a function, so in your case it should be written like this:

```
data () {
 return {
   aha: ""
 }
}
```